# Best method to Automate Identity Provider (IdP) initiated SSO in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, saml-2.0

I trying to programmatically create an AWS application within Azure AD with SAML identity provider. I have already done everything needed on the AWS side, but am struggling for Azure. I need to create the enterprise application, and then download the Federation Metadata XML file.

I know how to do this through the Azure console, but am trying to automate the process and need to do all of this through code. I have looked into Graph API and terraform, but cannot seem to find the best way to do this, and am looking for suggestions, or if anyone has done this before.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out a pretty decent way to do this using Microsoft Graph API, for anyone interested,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/amazon-web-service-tutorial